# target element in modal to change style

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a link on a page that opens a modal that has 3 buttons.  I want to change the font of one of those buttons to a different size.  I can't change the code on the page, but I can add javascript/jquery to a js file that the page uses.  What I have doesn't seem to be working correctly because when the page loads, the modal content is not known yet so when the user hits the page the source shows this:

```
<div id="aModal">
  <div id="modalContent">
    <div id="modalBody">
      <div id="acctContent"></div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

then after clicking the link it shows this:

```
<div id="aModal">
  <div id="modalContent">
    <div id="modalBody">
      <div id="acctContent">
        <div style="min-width: 300px;">
          <button class="modal-item">some text here</button>
          <button class="modal-item">some other text here</button>
          <button class="modal-item">some different text here</button>
        </div>        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

here is the javascript I'm using:

```
<script>
var targetButton = document.getElementById("acctContent").getElementsByClassName("modal-item");
var sContent = "some different text here"
for (var i=0; i <= targetButton.length; i++) {
    if (targetButton.innerHTML = sContent) {
        targetButton.style.fontSize = "small";
    }
}
</script>
```

Is it possible to case the javascript to be triggered maybe upon clicking the link?  Or any other solution?  I also have access to change the css, except there is nothing specific about the button besides the text content, I won't know how many buttons will display.
Thanks!

Comment: Does the button always have the same text?

Comment: if the modal causes a "shown" event you can trigger the javascript on that event.

Comment: @JohnnyCee - The button I want to target will always have the same text.

Comment: @fnostro - how would I find out if the modal causes that event?  Do you have example syntax on how to put that into an if statement?
Thank you!

Comment: it depends:  Bootstrap Modals have [these events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/modal/#events) and jQueryUI Dialogs can be initialized as a Modal and has [an open event](https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-open).  But if you are "rolling your own" you may not have any events as it sounds like you cannot change the original code. You'd have to see if the modal is a third party utility and check their docs

Comment: Then again you do have a button that triggers the modal so maybe you can act on that click event

Comment: Something else has been bothering me.  You are asking how to make a button text smaller, why?  What is the actual issue that you are trying to address?  Is it specific to the third button? Is the button too large for the dialog?

Comment: This is a request from a client, no problem we're trying to fix, they just want the font smaller.  We are using bootstrap so I tried this:
    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal'), function () {
        var targetButton = $('.modal-item');
        var sContent = 'some different text here';
        if ($(targetButton).innerHTML() = sContent) {
            targetButton.style.fontSize = "Small";
        }
    }
I'm unfamiliar with jquery/javascript, but this doesn't do anything.  I will look into the click event to open the modal.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add CSS to the page? If so, you can use a CSS selector to target the button and apply the CSS styles you need.

So, for example, to target the 2nd button:

```
#aModal button.modal-item:nth-of-type(2) {
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

EDIT: OK, I reread your question and now see you wrote, "I also have access to change the css, except there is nothing specific about the button besides the text content, I won't know how many buttons will display."

I added a question above.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what needs to trigger this but a CSS rule that acts on a pseudo class like `:hover` can be applied to any number of elements but will act individually so there is no need to check content.

```css
button.modal-item {
  transition: font-size .25s;
}

button.modal-item:hover {
  transition: font-size .75s;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="aModal">
  <div id="modalContent">
    <div id="modalBody">
      <div id="acctContent">
        <div style="min-width: 300px;">
          <button class="modal-item">some text here</button>
          <button class="modal-item">some other text here</button>
          <button class="modal-item">some different text here</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```